# Understanding associations in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, models

Seems I need to brush up on my associations in rails. At present I am trying to display all posts that have the department name as staff.

two models exist at present, posts and departments

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  attr_accessible :title, :comments, :department_id
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  attr_accessible :name, :post_id
  #Scopes
  scope :staff_posts, where(:name => "Staff") 
end
```

So i want to display all posts that have the department name staff

to do this i have put this in my controller

```
class PublicPagesController < ApplicationController

  def staffnews
    @staffpost = Department.staff_posts
  end

end
```

In my view i am trying to display all these posts like so

```
<% @staffpost.each do |t| %>
  <h2><%= t.title %>
  <h2><%= t.comments %></h2>
<% end %>
```

Clearly going wrong somewhere as i get undefined method nil, even though i have 3 posts with the name 'Staff'

Can someone please explain where i am misunderstanding the association as would love to get this right

EDIT

Routes

```
scope :controller => :public_pages do 
get "our_news"

match "our_news/staffnews" => "public_pages#staffnews"
```

Comment: "Seems I need to brush up on my associations" - I recommend a book for that. Structured knowledge is way more useful than SO posts.

Comment: In controller it returns department with name staff. And you are using title and comments on on department objects thats why no method error is coming

Comment: @SergioTulentsev any recommendations apart from the regular rails docs, ie have you come across a blog or post that simplifies the explanation

Comment: I am not sure and I can't test it now as I am away from my laptop. But as far as I know you have declared the scope in Department model and `Department.staff_posts` will return the Departments with name 'staff'. I am not sure but `@staffposts = Department.staff_posts.first.posts` should fetch the posts. If this doesn't work then you can use `@staffposts = Department.find_by_name('staff').posts`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In controller it returns department with name staff. And you are using title and comments on on department objects thats why its giving nil method error.

Use like this:

```
 def staffnews
   @dept_staff = Department.staff_posts
 end

 <% @dept_staff.each do |ds| %>
   <% ds.posts.each do |p| %>
     <h2><%= p.title %></h2>
     <h2><%= p.comments %></h2>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

or

In post model create `named_scope`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  attr_accessible :title, :comments, :department_id
  scope :staff_posts, :include => :department, :conditions => {"departments.name" => "Staff"}
end


class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  attr_accessible :name, :post_id
end
```

Controller:

```
def staffnews
  @staffpost = Post.staff_posts
end
```

View:  #No change

```
<% @staffpost.each do |t| %>
  <h2><%= t.title %></h2>
  <h2><%= t.comments %></h2>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `staff_posts` scope is only selecting the Departments with the name "Staff". Assuming you will have one and only one department named staff, you have a few ways to handle this.

This will find all departments with the name staff, and eager load the posts that go along with it:

```
@department = Department.where(name: "Staff").include(:posts).first
```

Since you are trying to scope Post, however, this belongs in Post. Here's an example using a method as scope:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  attr_accessible :title, :comments, :department_id

  def self.staff
    where(department_id: staff_department_id)
  end

  def staff_department_id
    Department.find_by_name!("Staff").id
  end

end
```

This way, you can use `@staff_posts = Post.staff` and iterate over that collection (Note: I don't recommend getting `staff_department_id` this way permanently. This could be set to a constant when the app boots up, or some other more robust solution).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the all the posts that have the department name staff by following changes:

class PublicPagesController < ApplicationController

```
def staffnews
    #get all the department which have name is staff
    departments = Department.where("name=?","staff")

    #get all the ids
    department_ids = departments.map(&:id)

    #retrieve post that department name is staff 
    @staffpost = Post.find_by_department_id(department_ids)
end
```

end

Comment: It's considered good practice to name variables according to their cardinality. Your first line would be better written as `departments = Department.where("name=?", "staff")` and change the next line accordingly. Just an unrelated comment.

Comment: Thank, I have changed the name of variables as you mention.